# How to setup a CNAME to map a custom domain to an Apple Mobile Me site

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, apple

My site is published with iWeb and is hosted at URL like this:

`http://web.me.com/foobar`

With pages like this:

`http://web.me.com/foobar/site/about.html`

I have a custom domain (e.g., `www.foo.com`) for this site.  According to [these instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1107), I should define a CNAME with my registrar that maps `www.foo.com` to `web.me.com`.

**My question is:**

After I configure the CNAME, what happens, precisely, when someone types in:

`http://www.foo.com`

Which URL are they really hitting?  And what will show up in the address bar?  (Obviously I don't want them to land on `http://web.me.com` but rather `http://web.me.com/foobar`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are also adding a little "URL redirection" too, but maybe not mentioning it. The CNAME will land any requests of www.foo.com to web.me.com. More than likely at web.me.com it will be looking at the HTTP request information and see that the original request/read came in for www.foo.com which will allow it to actually map to web.me.com/foobar.

Whether they "stealth" the return to show the "true" URL is not addressed. It may display the "true" URL in which the http address will then reflect web.me.com/foobar or if it is "stealthed" then the http address will remain www.foo.com or become www.foo.com/foobar.

Comment: Thanks.  The "stealthing" would be up to web.me.com, eh?

Comment: Correct. The web redirect will work either with or without it, it just keeps things looking nice...

Comment: @user48838 They do mask the "real" URL, btw.